# Is there any way to make Audacious music player playes still after it exits?

Tags: 16.04, music, rhythmbox, audacious

I am using Audacious as my default music player and Removed RhythmBox from my Ubuntu 16.04.

But I want to play music using Audacious and have the functionality of RhythmBox of continuing to play music after it exits while music can still be controlled from music menu

Is there any way to make Audacious play with control from music menu after it exits just like Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, go to View > Visualizations

[image]

On side menu, click "Plugins", then open "General" tab, you'll see few checkbox option. Enable the "Status Icon" one.

[image]

Open "Settings" to configure this plugin, below "Other Settings" section, enable "Close to system tray".

[image]

Audacious play-on-close in my 16.04 system.

[image]

Comment: If this answer did help, just click the little grey ☑ at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green. (Copied from [Fabby's canned comment](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15559258/))